# ¿Como funciona MASQUERADE en una cadena POSTROUTING en iptables?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iptables

Estoy intentando crear un firewall en mi red doméstica con una Raspberry Pi. El caso es que el primer paso es redireccionar el trafico del puerto eth0 a eth1 de mi Raspberry Pi, donde habrá la red del router del ISP(192.168.1.0) y mi red interna(10.0.0.0), respectivamente.

Para hacerlo, una de las soluciones que he encontrado en internet y que me ha servido es con iptables crear la regla siguiente(entre otras cosas):

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Me he seguido informando, y he visto que MASQUERADE lo que hace es cambiar la IP origen del paquete para que pueda salir hacia el router del ISP por la interfaz correspondiente.

Lo que no entiendo, es como puede volver el paquete de respuesta hacía mi host perteneciente a la red interna (10.0.0.0), ya que mandará el paquete a la IP de origen que ha sido enmascarada con iptables, pero no sabrá nunca cual es la verdadera.

Seguramente me estoy haciendo un buen lío, pero me gustaría que alguien me aclarara la duda, e incluso si conoce un método mejor para redireccionar los paquetes de eth0 a eth1, será bienvenido.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente estás haciendo **NAT** (*Network Address Translation*).

Lo que permite a un dispositivo como un router o una raspberry actuar como intermediario entre dos redes y dando lugar a que un grupo de ordenadores salga por una única direccion IP, eso en concreto se le conoce "enmascarar".

> ¿Como consigue mi router diferenciar los distintos equipos dentro de
> la red y a cual correspone el trafico?

Gracias a un fichero interno que se crea llamado Nat table, donde se guardan las referencias necesarias para poder manejar el trafico, como el puerto de origen y destino o la ip destino.

Te dejo las fuentes por si quieres ampliar la información:

Sobre NAT:

[fuente](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/26704-nat-faq-00.html)

[fuente](https://qastack.mx/ubuntu/466445/what-is-masquerade-in-the-context-of-iptables)

Sobre NAT table:

[Nat table](https://microchipdeveloper.com/tcpip:nat-translation-table)

[Foto Nat Table](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NAT_table.png)

Comment: Però esto aplica en el Postrouting, no? No acabo de entender como el paquete de retorno logra identificar el host real en la red 10.0.0.0. No sé si me explico.

Es una regla que segun yo entiendo solo aplica a la salida del paquete. Seguramente no lo tengo bien entendido.

Comment: Eso es gracias a un fichero interno que se crea llamado Nat table, donde se guardan las referencias necesarias para poder manejar el trafico, te dejo un ejemplo que te va a aclarar: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NAT_table.png

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la aclaración!!! Llevo días dandole vueltas por no entender como me estaba funcionando. En cuanto me dejen te otorgo la recompensa! :)

Comment: De nada! un placer haber sido de ayuda ^^